# reading InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I am getting some data from network using an Inputstream. I want to make a log to check if the InputStream has something on it. `Log("InputStream = "+ is.read())` and I get `InputStream = 123`
But later when I use it I get InputStream = -1. I guess is something related with the position of the iterator, but I haven't seen in the [API of Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) that you have to use a `reset()` (as when you use `mark()`) to read again the inputStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct - one read to a customer.  Once you use a stream or an iterator you can't use it again without resetting it.

Answer (score 1):

`InputStream` doesn't allow to "peek" at the next character; instead, all read methods block until data is available.

If you need peeking, use [Java NIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O). A [`Selector`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) can tell you if any channel has data ready.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap you stream in a [`PushbackInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html). Then you could do this:

```
int r = in.read();
Log("InputStream = "+ r);
in.unread(r);
```

and a following read will re-read that character

Comment: Will this not hang if no character is available?

Answer (score 0):

This [example](http://sites.google.com/site/trashgod/edasm) uses `mark()` and `reset()` to re-read the input stream, but it relies on  *a priori* knowledge of a  suitable `readlimit`. Depending on your needs, it may be a useable buffer strategy.